# Google App Engine fetching based on values in list

Tags: database, google-app-engine

Is there any way to do a query in GAE where I have a `list` of `userId`'s, and I want to fetch all `User`'s with `userId` in the `list`.

Something like `query.filter("userId IN", userIdList)`

If this is not possible, what's the closest alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is trivial if you fetch by key instead of running a query. If your user objects have their user id as their entity key, then you can do this:

```
# assume userIdList is a list of ints that are entity key ids
user_keys = [ndb.Key('User', k) for k in userIdList]
users = ndb.get_multi(user_keys)
```

Comment: Well my user Id list is actually by emails, so its a list of strings. Here's the question now: is it more efficient to fetch by keys rather than fetch by just an arbitrary user ID, which in this case is that user's email? Does fetching by key cost less reads?

Comment: I've asked a separate question about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10164283/fetching-by-key-vs-fetching-by-filter-in-google-app-engine

Comment: Fetching by key is particularly efficient here, because an 'IN' query evaluates to a separate query for every item in the list. So instead of N queries (each of which reads an index, then fetches the matching entity), you're doing a single batch get.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is exactly right. The `IN` operator exists for for this purpose. Did you try it?

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries

Comment: are you sure you can query/filter on key names/ids?

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize this is the ID of the entity. Actually you still can via metadata queries: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/metadataqueries#Kind_Queries

Comment: But, you'd be better off, just using multi get, as @mjibson suggests.

Comment: Well they're not key ids, its actually just a list of user emails, but since they're unique, I call them IDs. Am I better off fetching by keys than by user emails?

Comment: I've asked a separate question about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10164283/fetching-by-key-vs-fetching-by-filter-in-google-app-engine