# Fetching by key vs fetching by filter in Google App Engine

Tags: database, google-app-engine

I want to be as efficient as possible and plan properly. Since read and write costs are important when using Google App Engine, I want to be sure to minimize those. I'm not understanding the "key" concept in the datastore. What I want to know is would it be more efficient to fetch an entity by its key, considering I know what it is, than by fetching by some kind of filter?

Say I have a model called User and a user has an array(list) of commentIds. Now I want to get all this user's comments. I have two options:

1. The user's array of commentId's is an array of keys, where each key is a key to a Comment entity. Since I have all the keys, I can just fetch all the comments by their keys.
2. The user's array of commentId's are custom made identifiers by me, in this case let's just say that they're auto-incrementing regular integers, and each comment in the datastore has a unique commentIntegerId. So now if I wanted to get all the comments, I'd do a filtered fetch based on all comments with ID that is in my array of ids.

Which implementation would be more efficient, and why?

Comment: Have you considered a third option: user key is a parent (ancestor) of that user's Comment keys?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on that..

Comment: Meaning, instead of using a property list on your User model, you simply use the Datastore structure: Comment key has a parent, a user key. So that later, when you want to get all comments made by a user, you'd do e.g. `Comment.query(ancestor=user_key)` (in Python, NDB) or `ds.prepare(new Query("Comment", userKey))` (Java). In other words, you don't keep any additional entity property just to hold a list of comment keys.

Comment: I see..so fetching all comments with a common ancestor (being a certain user) is faster than fetching all comments with filter ownerId=5?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. Though, it all depends on the data surrounding your specific question. You should also consider how much it'll cost you to implement *and* maintain the code later on. It's always a tradeoff. One of the tools I'd highly recommend is Appstats - it'll tell you how many RPCs you're making and how much CPU you're consuming during a HTTP request/response (assuming you're making queries during that request).

Comment: A big caveat here: The answers are right in that get operations are much faster than queries (they use fewer quota resources, too). However, that won't help for your "get all comments by user X", because fetching by key would require you to store a list of comment IDs against the user record, which would mean incurring many additional write operations, which will more than outweigh any savings elsewhere. In this case, you're better off querying.

Comment: @alex A query with an ancestor filter is not notably faster than one without.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Fetching by key is the fastest way to get an entity from the datastore since it the most direct operation and doesn't need to go thru index lookup.
2. Each time you create an entry (unless you specified key_name) the app engine will generate a unique (per parent entity) numeric id, you should use that as ids for your comments.

Comment: Any chance you can elaborate on point 1? Why is it the fastest way?

Comment: @mohabitar: a pragmatic answer would point you [the app engine system status](http://code.google.com/status/appengine/detail/hr-datastore/2012/04/15#ae-trust-detail-hr-datastore-get-latency), a single datastore get (fetch by key) took ~30 ms, while a single query took ~90 ms.

Comment: @IbrahimArief btw notice that the HR Datastore get time adv is around 30ms while the (old, and "bad") MS Datastore is around 15ms.

Answer (score 1):

You should design a NoSql database (= GAE Datastore) based on usage patterns:

If you need to get all user's comments at once and never need to get one or some of them based on some criteria (e.g. query them), than the *most efficient* way, in terms of speed and cost would be to serialize all comments as a binary blob inside an entity (or save it to Blobstore).

But I guess this is not the case, as comments are usually tied to both users and to posts, right? In this case above advice would not be viable.

To answer you title question: `get` by key is always faster then `query` by a property, because query first goes through index to satisfy the property condition, where it gets the key, then it does the `get` with this key.